# How do I resolve a request failed issue while accessing a github csv file using url?

Tags: vue.js, github, drop-down-menu, remote-access, syncfusion

I am trying to create a Vue.js webapp. It has a dropdown menu that uses a csv file in github and accesses one of its columns as the items for the dropdown menu. I am using syncfusion to create the dropdownlist.

[image: Request Failed].

Can anyone help me solve this 'Request Failed' issue. The csv file has data of allmost all pulic listed companies in the world. Or is there another way to create url from csv file? Or even being able to access the local csv file data would be great.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to Desche App.</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="container" style="margin: 5rem auto 0; width: 20rem;">
        <br>
        <ejs-dropdownlist id="dropdownlist" :dataSource="remoteData" :fields="dataFields" :query="query"
          placeholder="Select a company name"></ejs-dropdownlist>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import { DropDownListPlugin } from '@syncfusion/ej2-vue-dropdowns';
import { DataManager, WebApiAdaptor } from '@syncfusion/ej2-data';
// import QueryString from 'qs';
Vue.use(DropDownListPlugin);
var remoteDataSource = new DataManager({
  url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azmart/IxFintech/main/identifier_mapper.csv',
  adaptor: new WebApiAdaptor,
  crossDomain: true
});
export default Vue.extend({
  data: function () {
    return {
      // query: new QueryString().from('identifier_mapper').select(['company_name', 'exchange_symbol']).take(6),
      remoteData: remoteDataSource,
      dataFields: { text: 'company_name', value: 'exchange_symbol' },
    };
  }
});
</script>

<style>
/* @import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/styles/material.css'; */

@import url('https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/material.css');

#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

This is my code. There are no errors running this. But the webapp says 'Request Failed.' when trying to load the data from url.

Answer (score 0):

The link you have used will return the data in CSV format. You need to convert the CSV data into an array of objects and then bind the data to the DropdownList component. For more information, please refer to the code snippet and sample below.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to Desche App.</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="container" style="margin: 5rem auto 0; width: 20rem;">
        <br>
        <ejs-dropdownlist id="dropdownlist" :dataSource="remoteData" :fields="dataFields" :query="query"
          placeholder="Select a company name" :created="onCreated"></ejs-dropdownlist>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import { DropDownListPlugin } from '@syncfusion/ej2-vue-dropdowns';
import { Query } from '@syncfusion/ej2-data';
Vue.use(DropDownListPlugin);

export default Vue.extend({
  data: function () {
    return {
      query: new Query().take(100),
      remoteData: [],
      dataFields: { text: 'company_name', value: 'exchange_symbol' },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onCreated: function () {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azmart/IxFintech/main/identifier_mapper.csv');
      xhr.onload = () => {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          const csvData = xhr.responseText;
          // Split CSV data into an array of rows
          const rows = csvData.split('\n');
          // Remove the header row
          rows.shift();
          // Split each row into an array of columns
          const data = rows.map((row) => {
            const columns = row.split(',');
            return {
              exchange_symbol: columns[0],
              company_name: columns[1],
              ticker: columns[2],
              market_cap: parseFloat(columns[3]),
              sector: columns[4],
              industry: columns[5],
            };
          });
          console.log(data);
          this.remoteData = data;
        } else {
          console.error(`Failed to fetch data: ${xhr.statusText}`);
        }
      };
      xhr.onerror = () => {
        console.error('Failed to fetch data');
      };
      xhr.send();
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

The onCreated function is called when the Syncfusion Vue DropdownList component is created. This function loads data from a remote server by sending a GET request to a CSV file hosted on GitHub.

When the CSV data is successfully loaded, the function performs the following operations:

- The CSV data is split into an array of rows, with each row
  represented as a string.
- The header row is removed from the array of rows.
- Each row is split into an array of columns, with each column
  represented as a string.
- Each row is transformed into a JavaScript object, with each column
  value mapped to a specific property name.
- The resulting array of JavaScript objects is assigned to the
  remoteData property of the Vue component, which serves as the data
  source for the dropdown list.

If the data loading fails, an error message is logged to the console.

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Vue_Dropdown_CSV_DataBind-688425747